# To Do List Array Ordering

Tags: javascript, arrays

I keep coming unstuck with a to do list I made.

So my issue is with sorting. When someone adds a to do I push an object to the array.

The problem is when you tick complete it goes to the completed section, but then if you decide to make it uncomplete again it goes back to the top of the list (I think that's the best way instead of going to the bottom of the list). Let me know if you think otherwise.

So it goes back to the top of the list but its array position never changed so on refresh it just goes back to its normal array position. I don't really want the list re-jigging on refresh.

I asked a similar question and got a reply saying to use the 'sort' method, so I added a 'iscomplete' property on the object so when you complete then uncomplete it sorts these to the top.

But if you have multiple items completing then uncompleting you just get the same problem.

Not sure how to address this issue.

HTML

```
<div class="to-do">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="to-do-entry">
      <div class="to-do-task-holder">
        <input id="task-holder" type="text" placeholder="Enter a to do!">
        <svg id="add-to-do" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                <line x1="12" y1="5" x2="12" y2="19"/>
                <line x1="5" y1="12" x2="19" y2="12"/>
            </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Task -->
  <!-- Uncompleted -->
  <div class="container">
    <h3 class="to-do-title to-do-title-uncompleted">Uncompleted Tasks</h3>
  </div>
  <ul id="uncompleted-tasks"></ul>
  <!-- Completed -->
  <div class="container">
    <h3 class="to-do-title to-do-title-completed">Completed Tasks</h3>
  </div>
  <ul id="completed-tasks"></ul>
</div>
```

JS

```
// To do list

var storeToDos = [];

// Cache DOM
var addToDo = document.getElementById('add-to-do');
var taskHolder = document.getElementById('task-holder');
var uncompleteTasks = document.getElementById('uncompleted-tasks');
var completedTasks = document.getElementById('completed-tasks');

// Bind events
var bindEvents = function(listItem, checkboxEventHandler) {
  // Delete
  var deleteToDo = listItem.querySelector('.delete-to-do');
  deleteToDo.addEventListener('click', deleteTask);
  // Edit
  listItem.querySelector('.edit-to-do').addEventListener('click', editTask);
  listItem.querySelector('.edit-holder').addEventListener('keyup', editTaskEnter);
  // Checkbox
  var checkbox = listItem.querySelector('input.edit-to-do');
  checkbox.onchange = checkboxEventHandler;
}

// Create list item
var createListItem = function() {
  var listItem = document.createElement('li');
  var deleteToDo = document.createElement('div');
  deleteToDo.innerHTML = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="none" stroke="#FFF" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M7.1 7.1l9.8 9.8M7.1 16.9l9.8-9.8"/></svg>';
  deleteToDo.classList.add('delete-to-do');
  var editToDo = document.createElement('div');
  editToDo.innerHTML = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="none" stroke="#FFF" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M16 3l5 5L8 21H3v-5z"/></svg>';
  editToDo.classList.add('edit-to-do');
  var toDoStatus = document.createElement('input');
  toDoStatus.type = 'checkbox';
  toDoStatus.classList.add('edit-to-do');
  var editHolder = document.createElement('input');
  editHolder.type = 'text';
  editHolder.classList.add('edit-holder');

  listItem.appendChild(deleteToDo);
  listItem.appendChild(editToDo);
  listItem.appendChild(toDoStatus);
  listItem.appendChild(editHolder);

  return listItem;
}

// Add task
var addTask = function(e) {
  var listItem = createListItem();
  var taskHolderValue = taskHolder.value;
  if(taskHolderValue) {
    document.querySelector('body').classList.add('to-do-activated');
    var taskHolderElement = document.createElement('label');
    taskHolderElement.classList.add('to-do-item');
    listItem.insertBefore(taskHolderElement, listItem.childNodes[0]);
    var storeToDosObj = {
      value: '',
      id: null,
      completed: false,
      didComplete: false
    }
    storeToDosObj.value = taskHolderValue;
    var listId = storeToDosObj.id = Date.now();
    listItem.id = listId;
    uncompleteTasks.insertBefore(listItem, uncompleteTasks.childNodes[0]);
    var storedToDos = localStorage.getItem('todos');
    if(storedToDos) {
      var storedToDosArr = JSON.parse(localStorage.todos);
      storedToDosArr.push(storeToDosObj);
      localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(storedToDosArr));
    } else {
      console.log(storeToDos);
      storeToDos.push(storeToDosObj);
      localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(storeToDos));
    }
    taskHolderElement.innerHTML = taskHolderValue;
    bindEvents(listItem, taskCompleted);
    taskHolder.value = '';
  } else {
    alert("You didn't add a to a to do!");
  }
}

var addTaskEnter = function(e) {
  var key = 'which' in e ? e.which : e.keyCode;
  if(key === 13) {
    addTask();
  }
}

// Delete task
var deleteTask = function() {
  var listItem = this.parentNode;
  var parentItem = listItem.parentNode;
  var getToDos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos'));
  for(var b=0; b<getToDos.length; b++) {
    if(getToDos[b].id == listItem.id) {
      getToDos.splice(b, 1);
      localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(getToDos));
    }
  }
  parentItem.removeChild(listItem);
}

// Edit task
var editTask = function() {
  var defaultValue = this.parentNode.querySelector('label').innerHTML;
  var listItem = this.parentNode;
  var listParent = this.parentNode;
  var editedValue = listParent.querySelector('input.edit-holder').value;
  if(listItem.classList.contains('editing') && editedValue) {
    listParent.querySelector('label').innerHTML = editedValue;
    var storedLocalStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.todos);
    for(var d=0; d<storedLocalStorage.length; d++) {
      if(storedLocalStorage[d].id == listItem.id) {
        storedLocalStorage[d].value = editedValue;
        storedLocalStorage[d].completed = false;
        localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(storedLocalStorage));
      }
    }
  }
  listItem.classList.toggle('editing');
  listParent.querySelector('input.edit-holder').value = '';
}

// Edit task enter
var editTaskEnter = function(e) {
  var key = 'which' in e ? e.which : e.keyCode;
  if(key === 13) {
    editTask.call(this);
  }
}

// Task completed
var taskCompleted = function() {
  var listItem = this.parentNode;

  var storedCompletion = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos'));
  if(storedCompletion) {
    if(listItem.classList.contains('editing')) {

    }
    for(var e=0; e<storedCompletion.length; e++) {
      if(storedCompletion[e].id == listItem.id) {
        if(storedCompletion[e].completed === true) {
          this.parentNode.classList.add('completed');
          uncompleteTasks.insertBefore(listItem, uncompleteTasks.childNodes[0]);
          this.parentNode.classList.remove('completed');
          bindEvents(listItem, taskCompleted);
          storedCompletion[e].completed = false;
          storedCompletion[e].didComplete = false;
        } else {
          completedTasks.insertBefore(listItem, completedTasks.childNodes[0]);
          this.parentNode.classList.add('completed');
          bindEvents(listItem, taskUncompleted);
          storedCompletion[e].completed = true;
          storedCompletion[e].didComplete = true;
        }
        localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(storedCompletion));
      }
    }
  }
}

// Task uncompleted
var taskUncompleted = function() {
  var listItem = this.parentNode;
  uncompleteTasks.insertBefore(listItem, uncompleteTasks.childNodes[0]);
  this.parentNode.classList.remove('completed');
  bindEvents(listItem, taskCompleted);

  if(localStorage) {
    var storedCompletion = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos'));
  }

  for(var f=0; f<storedCompletion.length; f++) {
    if(storedCompletion[f].id == listItem.id) {
      storedCompletion[f].completed = false;
      localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(storedCompletion));
    }
  }
}

// Add task
addToDo.addEventListener("click", addTask);
taskHolder.addEventListener("keyup", addTaskEnter);

// Loop over complete tasks
for(i=0; i<completedTasks.length; i++) {
  var listItem = completedTasks[i];
  uncompleteTasks.appendChild(listItem);
  bindEvents(listItem, completedTasks);
}

// Render local storage
var getToDos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos'));
getToDos.reverse();
getToDos.sort(function(a, b){
  return b.didComplete > a.didComplete;
});
if(getToDos) {
  for(i=0; i<getToDos.length; i++) {
    var listItem = createListItem();
    listItem.id = getToDos[i].id;
    var storedListItem = document.createElement('label');
    storedListItem.innerHTML = getToDos[i].value;
    listItem.insertBefore(storedListItem, listItem.childNodes[0]);
    if(getToDos[i].completed === true) {
      listItem.querySelector('input').checked = true;
      completedTasks.appendChild(listItem);
      listItem.classList.add('completed');
    } else {
      uncompleteTasks.appendChild(listItem);
    }
    bindEvents(listItem, taskCompleted)
  }
}

if(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos')).length > 0) {
  document.querySelector('body').classList.add('to-do-activated');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a lot of code to sort through.

In a nutshell what you want is when you move the item around, move it around in the underlying array, not just in your rendered HTML.

The reason it gets out of what is because you're only putting it at the top of the HTML element, but the underlying data isn't being rearranged.

When you go to complete/uncomplete an item, in addition to rendering it in the DOM, you should also move the item in your stored items.

Something like this would move the item from it's current place to the top of the list:

```
const storedItems = []; // get from somewhere
let indexOfItem = 5; // the item you're going to move

storedItems.shift(storedItems.splice(indexOfItem, 1)[0]);
```

What that'll do is remove the item from it's current spot (with `splice()`), and then will `shift()` (put it on the front) of the array.

That will let you keep array in order with your DOM. When you go to complete it, you can do something similar, just change the indices to go in the equivalent place they go for the DOM.

A better solution may be to have one function that re-renders the whole DOM based on your stored data, then all of the functions just change they array and tell it to redraw. That's frameworks like React and AngularJS do (though they do have some fancy optimizations in there).

Answer (score 0):

You posted a lot of code, including a lot of functions that aren't really relevant to the problem so it's harder to give suggestions.

Maybe when a user unchecks an item you can just remove the task from the array and re-add it to the front of the array? You can use the [unshift](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unshift.asp) method to prepend something to the front of the array.